# Some calls cause stack unwinding, though no C++ exception is thrown

Tags: exception, visual-c++, assert, stack-unwinding

I use Visual Studio Native Unit Test Framework for C++. When an assertion fails, next statements aren't executed and local objects destructors are called, so it seems like an exception is thrown, but I can't catch any C++ exception by `catch (...)` clause. After some experiments, I noticed that `__int2c()` call (that triggers the 2c interrupt, due to documentation), for example, has the same effect. By this day I was aware only about exceptions that have such behavior. Could you give me some hint about what can be the reason in this case?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a code sample

```
void func()
{
    struct Foo
    {
        ~Foo()
        {
            // this code is executed
        }
    };

    Foo foo;

    try
    {
        Assert::IsTrue(false);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // this code is not executed 
    }

    // this code is not executed
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @Mgetz Yes, added it to description

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular framework, but some of them have `return` statement baked into their assertion macros, precisely to terminate the test early once a precondition is found to be violated. Often, you would write a test assuming that previous asserts succeeded.

Comment: Assert::IsTrue is not a macros, but a function call